# There are physical volumes missing

Tags: lvm

I've got a logical volume on my virtual Debian server and it seems to be missing.

I've tried to active it by issuing `lvchange -ay` or `vgchange -ay` and the result was:

> Refusing activation of partial LV srv/vmails.  Use '--activationmode partial' to override.

By adding `'--activationmode partial` I can active the logical volume and after mounting the volume everything seems fine.

I tried running `pvscan -v` and it lists all corresponding physical volumes but also states that:

> There are 4 physical volumes missing.

But they're not, they're up and running!

I can verify that by running `blkid` on drive and comparing the results with UUIDs in `/etc/lvm/backup/srv`. However it is notable that some of these PVs are marked with missing flag in `/etc/lvm/backup/srv` and also `/etc/lvm/archive`:

```
flags = ["MISSING"]
```

Also running `pvs` shows all of the physical volumes but as you can see some of them are marked as missing:

```
PV                     VG         Fmt  Attr 
/dev/vdd               srv        lvm2 a-m
```

Running `lvs -v`:

```
There are 4 physical volumes missing.
There are 4 physical volumes missing.

LV        VG      #Seg  Attr        Maj Min KMaj KMin 
vmails    srv       6   -ri-----p-  -1  -1   -1   -1
```

What does this missing means?
How can I diagnose or fix the issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Cause:

> Once a device is marked as missing (such as if it cannot be found during a scan and the volume group is activated in "partial" mode), it may need to be manually restored.

#### Fix:

> This resolution only applies to situation where the device is available, contains the expected metadata, and shows up in the output of lvm scans.
>
> ```
> vgextend --restoremissing <volume group> <physical volume>
> ```

---

In my case, I first removed missing flag from physical volumes using the command mentioned above. Then I did run a `fsck` on the logical volume, seems it was not unmounted cleanly. It solved the issue.

<sub>*Solution from [here](https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=mmr_kc-0119236)*</sub>
<sub>Related: [[linux-lvm] LVM says physical volumes are missing, but they are not](https://www.redhat.com/archives/linux-lvm/2016-May/msg00091.html)</sub>